# Special Pythagorean Triplet

Tags: java, pythagorean

What's wrong with my code? It prints 2,2 when the correct answer is clearly 6,8

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int answer = 0;
    int j = 4;
    while (j == 4) {
        for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
            for (b = 1; b <= 10; b++) {
                answer = a * a + b * b;
                if (answer == 100) {
                    j = 10;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(a + " " + b);
}
```

Comment: It's there to check whether the while loop shall stop or continue

Comment: Why not just `while(answer != 100)`?

Answer (score 6):

`if(answer == 100);`
you have an extra semicolon after your if.

This will  cause it to execute the `j = 10;` no matter what `answer` equals

Comment: the way you are incrementing `a` and `b`, `a` will always be equal to `b`, so  they can never be 6 and 8. they will go (1,1) (2,2) etc.

Comment: Yes but it still prints 11,11

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing a and b at the same time. In your code, the two numbers will always be equal. Also, you are not testing for a match when you exit the loop.

Comment: i did a for loop,to increment them separately but it still prints 11,11

Comment: remove the while loop, label the first for loop `outer` and the replace the `j=10` with `break outer;`. Your j=10 will not break the inner loops.